# Javascript: Setting an input field value is not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I use this piece of javascript to create an input field with some data (*v* and *k* are set):

```
element = document.createElement('input');
element.value = v;
element.name = k;
```

This works in Chrome, but in Internet Explorer (tested with v11), only the `name` attribute is set and not the `value`.

Strangely, when I use jQuery, this works:

```
element = document.createElement('input');
$(element).attr("value", v);
element.name = k;
```

Why isn't plain javascript working here? It should work, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535126%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**Update**

I expected `element.value` to create a value attribute, but it doesn't. Indeed the value is set correctly, but it doesn't show that in a newly created value attribute or a change of the existing value attribute. It seems I tested this the wrong way.

Comment: You're missing semicolons everywhere. and `document.createElement 'input'` should be `document.createElement('input')`

Comment: Possibly for IE you have to define `type` of field as well?

Comment: `$(element).val(v)` - Try this.

Comment: Are v and k variables?

Comment: @AdamMerrifield You're right, I mistakenly copy pasted coffeescript in here, I've converted it to JS. (Reminds me to check the compilation, but these lines are the same in JS.)

Comment: @VisioN I've tried that, didn't work.

Comment: This works in IE11: http://jsfiddle.net/rL2ta/

Comment: @shaunakde Thanks, that's better, but I try to make it work without jQuery.

Comment: "Not working", how is that detected? As you can see at Yuriy's fiddle, your code works as it is.

Comment: Agree with Teemu -- define "not working". Also, does the variable `v` actually have data/is defined? What kind of form element are you trying to create? Setting an element value is pretty standard stuff. You should be able to step through this and see where it fails.

Comment: Your code doesn't create a `value` attribute in Chrome either ...

Comment: @Teemu, you're right. I was trying to solve a bug in IE and wrongfully figured this was it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element.value = v` works, it just doesn't create an HTML attribute, but it does set the value. It will create `<input name="myname">` only, but the value is still there (e.g visible in UI)

**Demo 1: http://jsfiddle.net/rL2ta/**

If you do want to create actual HTML attribute - use `element.setAttribute('value', v);` - will create `<input value="value" name="myname">`

**Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/ygalanter/rL2ta/1/**